# Recurse within binary tree's node class

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I have successfully written a method to print the values of all the nodes in the subtree rooted at a given node (code pasted below under the label "Working Code"). However, this printTree method is in the Main class (as opposed to being in the Node class itself). I am wondering if it is possible (and ideal?) to rewrite the code so that the printTree method is in the Node class itself? My attempt is below (code pasted below under the label "Non Working Code"), but it threw a Null Pointer Exception. Thank you!

WORKING CODE:

```
public class Node {

    int value;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public Node(int value, Node left, Node right)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

public class Main {


    public static void printTree(Node current)
    {

        if (current != null)
        {
            System.out.println(current.value);
            printTree(current.left);
            printTree(current.right);
        }

        return;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        Node a = new Node(3, new Node(4, null, null), new Node(5, null, null));

        printTree(a);

    }
}
```

NON WORKING CODE (in Node class):

```
public void printTree()
{
    Node current = this;

    if (current != null)
    {
        System.out.println(current.value);
        current.left.printTree();
        current.right.printTree();
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem may be to do with the line Node current = this, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the `Node current = this;` line. But in the

```
current.left.printTree();
current.right.printTree();
```

lines.

Because even when current is not null, current.left or current.right could be null. And you are trying to invoke `printTree()` on a null object.

**Fix:**

```
if (current != null)
{
    System.out.println(current.value);
    if (current.left != null)
        current.left.printTree();
    if (current.right != null)
        current.right.printTree();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand what you're trying to do, but my concern is that now we're checking whether a node is null twice (e.g. first when you do if (current.left != null) and second when you do if (current != null)). Is there any way to rewrite the code so that we don't do null checks for the same node more than once?

Comment: Actually, the `current != null` check is not necessary anymore.  Like Abishek himself noted elsewhere, `current` can never be null, because it is assigned from `this`, which can never be null.

Comment: You can remove the `if (current != null)` check. Because your current is always `this` and `this` will never be null.

Comment: Or even better, you dont need a `current` reference at all. You can directly call `left.printTree()` and `right.printTree()`

Comment: Thank you. To clarify: In this recursion, we have two recursive cases, but no base cases, right? The first recursive case being if (current.left != null), and the second being if (current.right != null)?